# Actor and Sprite, who should own these properties?

Tags: sprites, gameobject, oop

I'm writing sort of a 2D game engine for making the process of creating games easier. It has two classes, Actor and Sprite. Actor is used for interactive elements (the player, enemies, bullets, a menu, an invisible instance that controls score, etc) and Sprite is used for animated (or not) images with transparency (or not).

The actor may have an assigned sprite that represents it on the screen, which may change during the game. E.g. in a top-down action game you may have an actor with a sprite of a little guy that changes when attacking, walking, and facing different directions, etc.

Currently the actor has `x` and `y` properties (its coordinates in the screen), while the sprite has an `index` property (the number of the frame currently being shown by the sprite).
Since the sprite doesn't know which actor it belongs to (or if it belongs to an actor at all), the actor must pass its `x` and `y` coordinates when drawing the sprite.
Also, since a actors may reset its sprite each frame (and usually do), the sprite's `index` property must be passed from the old to the new sprite like so (pseudocode):

```
function change_sprite(new_sprite)
    old_index = my.sprite.index
    my.sprite = new_sprite()
    my.sprite.index = old_index % my.sprite.frames
end
```

I always thought this was kind of cumbersome, but it never was a big problem.

Now I decided to add support for more properties. Namely a property to draw the sprite rotated, a property to draw it flipped, it a property draw it stretched, etc. These should probably belong to the sprite and not the actor, but if they do, the actor would have to pass them from the old to the new sprite each time it changes... On the other hand, if they belonged to the actor, the actor would have to pass each property to the sprite when drawing it (since the sprite doesn't know which actor it belongs to, and it shouldn't, since sprites aren't just meant to be used by actors, really). Another option I thought of would be having an extra class that owns all these properties (plus `index`, `x` and `y`) and links an actor with a sprite, but that doesn't come without drawbacks.

So, what should I do with all these properties?

Comment: A small addition to some excellent answers below: I'd consider separating the *drawing* of sprites from the `Sprite` class. Then, `Sprite` becomes just a container/manager of the current frame, and a separate `Renderer` would be responsible for drawing.

Comment: @Torious Hmm... currently a Sprite is, in essence, just a bunch of `Image`s. Sprite.draw just calls the draw method of the image currently being shown in the animation (as determined by `index`). Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to deal with the problem you're describing is to do this:

```
class Transform
{
   public int x;
   public int y;
   public float rotation;
}
class Actor
{
   public Sprite s;
   public Transform t;
}
class Sprite
{
   public Transform t;
}
```

Now your data is encapsulated in one class ref'd by both Actor and Sprite. As for that separation, yes I think that's a good idea as the actor is essentially game logic, and the sprite is a view -- they are in this sense completely decoupled for cleaner code.

So you can take that as a more general, "yes" to your final suggestion. Push things out into intermediary classes where appropriate.

Comment: That circular reference is undesirable.  The asker specified, correctly, that the sprite should not know about the actor.  The sprite is a lower level rendering utility, and should not have a reference to a higher level complex game object.

Comment: @ktodisco True, that was just carelessness. Removed.

Comment: Guess I'm gonna go with this. For now, at least. A big thanks to everyone who tried to help!

Answer (score 2):

Each object should own its own properties. If other objects need to know those properties, let them query for them.

Your sprites probably don't have an intrinsic position, and they don't know how to get a position to be rendered because they may have to get that information from more than just Actors. So, you need a class that mediates between them. You might have an ActorView that holds a reference to the Actor and contains an instance of Sprite. When the Actor moves, ActorView is notified, and knows where to draw the sprite. The ActorView could also hold the current frame of animation, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Classes and objects are just bundled functionality, nothing more. And that way you should work with them.
Ideally you should build your classes around composition. The more advanced object should consist out of multiple smaller objects, and do all the communication needed between the smaller objects. The smaller objects should do nothing on their own and should know nothing about their parent. They just should do what is wanted from them.
In the case of this question that would look like this:

```
class Actor
{
  Sprite sprite;
  int x, y;
  float rotation;
  [...]
  void draw()
  {
    sprite.draw(x, y, rotation);
  };
  void update(dTime)
  {
    sprite.advanceAnimation(dTime);
    [...]
  };
  [...]
}
```

Comment: Well, you are pretty much describing how my system currently looks like. How do you suggest I solve the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, either you adapt the sprite class to what you need or you make a global Renderer class and you adapt that. In my personal project I use the Renderer approach as it's more flexible.

Comment: It's more flexible because I can apply those transformations to any Drawable class not just Sprites.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what you said souds very ambiguous. "adapt the sprite class to what you need"? "make a global Renderer class and you adapt that"?

Comment: @GerardoMarset Well you need to implement the feature "somewhere", that's what I meant with adapt. Where you implement it really depends on how your engine looks like. For example if all you'll ever need is your sprite class you can implement it there. But if you need more control about the rendering you should implement a class for the Renderer.

Comment: As example, In my library the sprite is calling "RenderEngine::GetTransformedRect(x, y, width, height);"  GetTransformedRect calls getTransformedRect in the currently active instance of the RenderEngine and returns the given rectangle with all those transformations applied. These Transformations are set by the actors or the scene itself, not by the Sprites. There are other classes which uses this GetTransformedRect-method amongst others my Font class.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you encounter a situation like this, there are a couple of questions you can ask yourself to determine the what the best structure is going forward:

- Is one class a more complex version of the other class?
- Should one class know about the other?
- What overall purpose is the class supposed to serve?
- Is one class a utility to be used by more complex class?

If you answer yes to the first question, then inheritance is what you're looking for.  For example, a regular sprite, or a sprite that supports multitexturing.  In the case you're describing, the answer is probably no, an `Actor` is not a more complex `Sprite`.  I think you are right that the `Sprite` class should not know about the `Actor` class, because, tying into the fourth question, the `Sprite` class is really a rendering utility for the `Actor` class; the Actor class relies on the `Sprite` class to draw itself on screen.

So, the `Actor` class should contain an instance of the `Sprite` class, in the same way that a `GameObject` in a 3D engine would have a `Model` to represent itself in the world.

To get to the specifics of your question, it seems like the root of your problem is your concern in how much maintenance the `Actor` class is going to have to handle for its `Sprite`.  You mentioned that the `Sprite` instance often changes every frame, and the `Actor` would have to be responsible for updating it (I'm guessing this is for 2D animation?).  I think this is where your structure goes wrong.  What I would suggest is to create an `AnimatedSprite` class, which is responsible for the update of it's current on-screen sprite, and would store the 'index' of its animation.  It's API could include functions such as `animate`, `stop`, etc; everything you might want an animated sprite to do.  For position, your `Sprite` class' draw-call should take in the position where it is to be drawn.

What's most important is that a whole class instance inside of your `Actor` class should not have to be reconstructed every frame.  If that becomes necessary, you should probably look for areas of improvement in your architecture.

Comment: It's preferred when an answer is downvoted that an explanation is provided.  I'd like to know how I could improve my answer.

Comment: Sprites handle animation already. The Sprite isn't likely to be changed every frame, but to be _re-set_ every frame. Something like `if not occupied then set_sprite(SpriteIdle)` in a method that is called every frame is common. That's what I meant. (It wasn't me who downvoted you, by the way.)

Comment: @GerardoMarset Hmm.. I guess I'm just confused about why the `Actor` needs to perform maintenance on the `Sprite` every frame.  That paradigm just doesn't seem clean to me.

Comment: Since the sprite is usually set every frame, and the sprite owns `index`, `index` would be reset to 0 every frame if the actor didn't pass it from the old sprite to the new one.

Comment: @GerardoMarset But what does setting the sprite every frame accomplish?  What specifically does 'resetting' the sprite do?

Comment: It should do nothing at all. It's just most people wouldn't want to write `if not occupied and sprite is not SpriteIdle then set_sprite(SpriteIdle)`.

Comment: @GerardoMarset If it does nothing, then why is it necessary to call it?

Comment: It's not. It's just convenient enough to be common, I think.
In any case, even if the sprite isn't changed or re-set every frame, it would be counterintuitive (not to mention cumbersome) that things like the scaling of the sprite or its rotation angle are lost when changing it. Currently the Actor is in charge of making sure these things are kept.